# Possibility to check if NSData contains NSString

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm using NSData to store XML from a webpage. Is it possible to check the NSData if it contains `<?xml version="1.0"?>`?

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:link];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

Comment: Do you mean entire NSData is just encoded empty string or what?

Comment: @Artur the XML was getting eaten; I've fixed the question.

Comment: Well, can't you just convert it to a string then check if `[str rangeOfString:@"<?xml"].location != NSNotFound`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `NSData` object contains raw binary data. To evaluate it's contents you first need to convert that data to specific data type - in your case a string. You need to know which encoding was used to convert the data object.

Then you can use

```
NSString *myXMLContent = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Now that you have the content of your XML file in that string you can evaluate it as needed.

```
NSRange range = [myXMLContent rangeOfString:@"whatImLookingFor" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
//found the string
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 NSString* str = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:theData
                                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];


 if (str && [str length] > 0){
     NSLog(@"Contains string");
}else{
    NSLog(@"Does't contains string");

 }
```